# Why does Stripe use the Post method for updating resources

Tags: api, http, stripe-payments, standards, http-verbs

[According to the RFC `Put` is used to update an existing resource.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.6)

But, the Stripe API uses `Post` to update objects. Why is this?

For example, in the [Stripe Node Library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node)

```js
  update: stripeMethod({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '{id}',
  }),
```

the [`update` method](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/lib/StripeMethod.basic.js#L20) calls `POST`

I understand that there is no `Patch` method since the entire resource must be sent on every call, by why is the `Put` HTTP Verb not used in that case?

(Unlike this example from [an SO question about the Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391621/why-does-the-facebook-api-use-post-for-updating-records), the resource is identifiable by a single ID that is passed in the URL) eg the URL is simply [`/v1/customers/:id`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update?lang=curl)

[image: Stripe Customer Update API Docs]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting question!  From [your link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.6):

> The PUT method requests that the **enclosed entity** be stored under the
> supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an **already
> existing resource**, the enclosed entity **SHOULD be considered as a
> modified version** of the one residing on the origin server. [emphasis mine]

This means you must `PUT` the *entire* resource (changes and and non-changes alike).  Very few APIs are designed that way.

From the [spec for POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.5):

> The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the
> entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource
> identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line. POST is designed
> to allow a uniform method to cover the following functions:
>
> - Annotation of existing resources;

Many/most APIs have adopted `POST` as the way to update objects.

Some additional thoughts here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25909372/379538

Comment: Stripe might have considered `PATCH` for partial updates. But [RFC 5789](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789) that introduces `PATCH` was written in 2010, the same year Stripe was incorporated.